# Manipulate the sort result considering the user preference - database

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

Suppose we have a simple database containing following data:

```
        name
        apple
        pear
        banana
        grape
```

User want to sort those fruits by the name, and we will have, with no surprise

```
         apple
         banana
         grape
         pear
```

However, for some reason, user would like to place `pear` as the 3rd fruit ,that means he would like to have :

```
         apple
         banana
         pear
         grape
```

And, importantly, the user want to preserve this order when he want to sort the fruits by name thereafter.

How should we tackle this problem? Of top of my head, we could add a field `user_sort_id`, which will be updated when user sort and manipulate the sort result and we will use that filed as the sort key.

```
                       init value       -> sort by name         ->place pear as the seconds
        name           user_sort_id 
        apple            0                     0                          0
        pear             1                     3                          2  
        banana           2                     1                          1  
        grape            3                     2                          3
```

This approach should work in theory. However, in practice, I can not think of an elegant and fast SQL statement that could accomplish this. Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: Can i ask what it happerns in case you add carrot for example. Does the pear string appears after banana or after carrot?

Comment: A hidden sort key is really the only solution since there is otherwise no rule by which the items could be sorted.  The sort key would have to be user-specific presumably.  One thing that used to be very irritating about Netflix's queue was explicitly manipulating the sort key.  They should have *at least* numbered them in increments of ten to make reordering simpler.

Comment: @niktrs: Great question. I think i will put it at the last ,regardless of the name, until you do another sort. In our case, actually we don't consider the case of new insert.

Comment: Check my answer to understand better why i asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each user to have independent sort orders, you need another table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_sort_order (
    name VARCHAR(?) NOT NULL REFERENCES your-other-table (name),
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users (user_id),
    sort_order INTEGER NOT NULL                -- Could be float or decimal
);
```

Then ordering is easy.

```
SELECT name 
FROM user_sort_order
WHERE user_id = ?
ORDER BY sort_order
```

There's no magic bullet for updating.

- Delete all the user's rows, and insert rows with the new order. (Brute force always works.)
- Update every row with the new order. (Could be a lot of UPDATE statements.)
- Track the changes in your app, and update only the changed rows and the rows that have to be "bumped" by the changes. (Parsimonious, but error-prone.)
- Don't let users impose their own sort order. (Usually not as bad an idea as it sounds.)

Comment: +1 yes, this approach works. I am looking for better way than this brute force approach.

Comment: "Brute force" is kind of a fuzzy term here. The third option--track  changes at the application level, and update only rows that need to be changed--isn't brute force, but would probably require one SQL statement per changed row. The first option--delete all the user's rows and insert rows with the new order--might only take two SQL statements. (Under PostgreSQL, it can be done with two SQL statements.)